# Dumping select GPUView events

Tags: windows, performance, xperf

Is there a way to dump specific events, for example, only the NT events corresponding to a specific process + DX events, into a text file from GPUView or xperf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Neither xperf nor GPUView support this. You can try extracting the desired events by yourself by using [TraceEvent](http://bcl.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TraceEvent%20Class%20Overview&referringTitle=TraceEvent) .Net library, [Windows APIs for retreiving events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363692%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or the [tracerpt tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732700%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).  HTH.